# How to setup two-way routing with Tomato Wireless Client mode (different subnets)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, subnet, tomato

Currently I have a Netgear R7000 as my main router, with internet coming from a Moto Surfboard SB6141 Cable Modem.  I have a Linksys E3000 running Toastman TomatoUSB connected to the R7000 as a Wireless Client.

#### R7000 (Main Router)

> **WAN IP:** DCHP from cable modem
>
> **LAN IP:** 192.168.1.1
>
> **DCHP Range:** 192.168.1.150 - 192.168.1.199

#### E3000 (Wireless Client)

> **WAN IP:** 192.168.1.110 (static assignment from R7000)
>
> **LAN IP:** 192.168.2.1
>
> **DHCP Range:**: 192.168.2.150 - 192.168.2.199

I also configured a static route on the R7000 to subnet `192.168.2.0` via gateway `192.168.1.110` (E3000 LAN IP).

With this setup the devices on the `192.168.2.0` subnet can access devices on the `192.168.1.0` subnet as well as the internet.  However devices on the `192.168.1.0` subnet can't access devices on the `192.168.2.0` subnet (I need this).

I understand that there is double-NATing going on by default so I tried changing the E3000 mode from "Gateway" to "Router" -- this gave me the access between subnets
but devices on the `192.168.2.0` subnet lost internet access.

Is what I want to do possible? What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I understand that I can set the secondary router up as a Wireless Ethernet Bridge (with all devices on the same subnet), but I'd like to get this working with the separate subnets if possible -- I don't want to rely on the Wireless connectivity for hard-wired devices to even get an IP address.